# Errors Inserting Now() into a datetime field (SQL Server 2005 9.0.5057)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, asp-classic, vbscript

I am performing an insertion of a new row from an ASP form into a database on my server.

When I look at the entries in the server, it looks as though they are in fact adding but it does stop all function at the execute line:

```
With        
   .Parameters(@blahblah) = Request.Form("blahblah")  
   .Parameters("@lastUpdate") = Now()        
   ...         
   .Execute        
End With
```

These are the errors I get:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers 80040e07
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value./results.asp217

The entries that are added have the dates in the column as:

> 2011-11-28 15:52:13.000

I have a feeling it is the milliseconds which I was under the impression only appears when using DateTime2 SQL field.

A few things I've tried after researching with no luck:

- Adding 'Session.LCID = 2057' - some SQL servers have British or US settings, this overrides the users settings
- Trying a bunch of different date formats such as FormatDateTime(Now(), 0 - 5)
- I can use 'On Error Resume Next' but I would prefer to rectify properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us more code, especially the way you build a sql command and add a parameters.

Comment: What is the database datatype? And have you confirmed that your code is not writing the dates in the "wrong" order (US vs. British dates)? Could you write your datetime as Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") instead?

Comment: @Miika L. - See my comment about 'Adding 'Session.LCID = 2057' (Locale ID's) - this is what ensures the dates are passing through in the correct format. ToString() is also CStr() in vbscript. The database datatype is datetime (not datetime2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your additional information I would do it this way:

```
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@blahblah", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form("blahblah")
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@lastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = Now()
```

The best approach (if it's possible) would be leave updating the `lastUpdate` field to trigger on the database.

Comment: Triggering in the database, that's actually a good idea that I haven't thought of. I will see what I can do and let you know if this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to pass named parameters but if `NamedParameters` value is False (by default) parameter names will be ignored (append order of parameters will affects). See [NamedParameters](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/command_namedparameters.html) property.

Set the `your_command_object.NamedParameters` to `True` before execution.

Comment: Thanks but I think it looks like there is an issue with the formatting between asp.vbscript 'datetime' and SQL Server 2005 'datetime'.

Comment: You don't need any formatting to pass a datetime variable (dont't convert to string, pass as datetime) to a date-time typed parameter (all of them, date, datetime, smalldatetime, datetime2). Just try.

Comment: I have tried, a fair few variations also. This is interesting though:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee198928.aspx - not sure how I would specify Now() to use this format though (yyyymmddHHMMSS.xxx)